# Как на ASP.NET Core использовать https соединение?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https, asp.net-core

Подскажите примеры, как настроить https соединение на  ASP.NET Core (я не использую IIS - в проекте стандартный Kestrel)
Спасибо.

Comment: Можешь nginx в качестве прокси использовать.

Comment: @Alex78191 я ни разу ещё не работал с ним. Тогда встречный вопрос- всё перегонять через него и https настраивать на нём, а у себя на проекте просто http? это на производительности отразится сильно или есть вариант прямо в проекте настроить? какие плюсы nginx-а?

Comment: Можно Kestrell настроить https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/https

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144799/implementing-ssl-in-asp-net-core-with-kestrel

Comment: У тебя какая VS?

Comment: @Alex78191 VS 2017